# SIGSEGV on program exit with boost::log

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-libraries, boost-log

Some time ago we separate our big project with almost static libraries to many projects with dynamic libraries.

Since then we stated seeing problems on shutdown.

Sometimes, the process would not terminate. With gdb I found, that on object destruction a segfault occurs, but the process is blocked in `futex_wait`.

I've since improved the code, by creating global objects are now created in function, instead of global static data. That reduced the problem: it doesn't happen in my development environment anymore.

However, in test environment (rare) and in production environment (often) processes still get stuck on shutdown. So we need to restart container manually, or have some kind of health check.

We are trying to simulate this kind of situation on standalone docker container running under Kubernetes where we have the process running under circusd and we see following:

```
#0  malloc_consolidate (av=0xf47fc400 <main_arena>) at malloc.c:4151
#1  0xf46ff1ab in _int_free (av=0xf47fc400 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4057
#2  0xf48c6e68 in operator delete(void*) () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0xf52d173d in std::_Deque_base<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view, std::allocator<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view> >::~_Deque_base() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#4  0xf52d18b3 in std::deque<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view, std::allocator<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record_view> >::~deque() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#5  0xf52d1940 in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::bounded_fifo_queue<4000u, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::drop_on_overflow>::~bounded_fifo_queue() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#6  0xf52d462e in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::asynchronous_sink<cout_sink, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::bounded_fifo_queue<4000u, boost::log::v2_mt_posix::sinks::drop_on_overflow>
>::~asynchronous_sink() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#7  0xf52d47f4 in asynchronous_sink<cout_sink>::~asynchronous_sink() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#8  0xf52c199a in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_pd<asynchronous_sink<cout_sink>*, boost::detail::sp_ms_deleter<asynchronous_sink<cout_sink> >
>::dispose() () from /usr/local/lib/liblog.so.0
#9  0xf51f3e7b in boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core::~core() () from /usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.58.0
#10 0xf51f6529 in boost::detail::sp_counted_impl_p<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core>::dispose() () from /usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.58.0
#11 0xf51f6160 in boost::shared_ptr<boost::log::v2_mt_posix::core>::~shared_ptr() () from /usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.58.0
#12 0xf46bcfb3 in __cxa_finalize (d=0xf526fa88) at cxa_finalize.c:56
#13 0xf51eaab3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libboost_log.so.1.58.0
#14 0xf7769e2c in _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:252
#15 0xf46bcc21 in __run_exit_handlers (status=status@entry=0, listp=0xf47fc3a4 <__exit_funcs>, run_list_atexit=run_list_atexit@entry=true) at exit.c:82
#16 0xf46bcc7d in __GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:104
#17 0xf46a572b in __libc_start_main (main=0x8060dc0, argc=5, argv=0xffdd1514, init=0x8088090, fini=0x8088100, rtld_fini=0xf7769c50 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xffdd150c) at libc-start.c:321
#18 0x080630cc in ?? ()
```

I have no ideas how to progress from here. What is happening? Why do we get the segfault in `boost::log::core` destruction in this environment?

Does anyone have some advice how can I find it, probably, based on experience?

Comment: "(often) that happens" - what exactly here? It's not clear what symptoms still remain after your fixes

Comment: Segfault at destruction time is often caused by double delete on the same memory. Try using a shared pointer for those objects shared. Also I found this which may be related https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8642 However you mention two symptoms, process locking and segfault, which are mutually exclusive since the segfault would kill the process. Is the lockup due to a corefile being generated?

Comment: In addition to Rob's comment, the backtrace you included in your question does not indicate a crash. It would be helpful to see a backtrace with the segfault.

Comment: It is always helpful to run a faulty program in valgrind, double frees etc. can often be detected there.

Comment: @Rob We don't use raw pointers at all. Only shared. Yeah, I saw this tread, but on test/prod envs we use syslog logging (but trace in question  if from using std::cout sink).
@AndreySemashev it's actually all. Higher is only `SIGSEGV` and something like `malloc` file can't be openned.
@Wurmloch of course I use valgrind, but there are only records from oracle.

Comment: If malloc implementation is glibc then you can try using its debug features as well. See about `MALLOC_CHECK_` at (http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html). glibc will often output a diagnostic message before aborting the process if heap corruption is detected.

Comment: Regarding the lockup, it would be nice to see the backtrace as well.

Comment: Here is a guess: boost::log uses boost::thread_specific_ptr, which are destroyed on exit ( __run_exit_handlers ), if you have code that is also running at exit (say destructors of global objects) that use logging, maybe you are trying to log after the logging facilities have been destroyed.